# Perl one-liner to increment a value

Tags: perl

I want to increment every number in quotes in a file, one per line:

```
perl -pe 's/\"(\d+)\"/ 1 + $1 /ge' file
```

This strips the quotes, but how do add the quotes back in to the output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/\"(\d+)\"/ q{"} . (1 + $1) . q{"} /ge'
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, for the FAST answer -- I'm able to google this function now that i know about it (hadn't seen it before).

Comment: @chuckfinley: which function? The `q{"}` construct is identical to single quotes `'"'` which can't be used because they would terminate the one-line program

Comment: It worked for me. 24G file with "0-13000" and at the end of each line, now "1-13091". I'm on a Mac but I thought PERL was PERL...?

Answer (score 5):

You can use look-around assertions - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns.

So the regex becomes: `s/(?<=")(\d+)(?=")/ $1 + 1 /ge`

Answer (score 2):

And the golf winner is:

```
perl -pe's/"(\d+)"/"@{[1+$1]}"/g'
```

Comment: this is genius++

Answer (score 1):

One solution from many:

```
perl -lpe 's/"(\d+)"/$1+1/e;s/(.*)/"$1"/'
```

Comment: This doesn't work right. When I input `abc 1 "2" 3 "4" def`, it outputs this: `"abc 1 3 3 "4" def"`

Comment: Never mind, I missed the "one per line" part, it works fine given that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/(\d)/{"\"".(1+$1)."\""}/ge' file
```

Explanation: `e` modifier tells Perl to evaluate the replacing value (in curly brackets). And `1+$1` returns the incremented number.